# Using NodeJS as an HTTP Server- How to avoid spagetti?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, connect

I'd like to use nodejs as a light webserver for a project I'm working on. I'm mostly a PHP programmer so the way I'd do this is different than what I'm used to.

In this application i'm using angular to request some data. I want to format this as "/get/some_data". On my node end I'm using connect and pointing it statically to my http dir.

Now when I make a request for some data it seems the only thing people recommend is looking for that request and passing it back. This is a lot less organized than a file-structure like I'm used to where each file handles the request.

```
var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect();

app.use(connect.static("/my_http_dir"));
app.use(function(req, res)
{
    if(req.originalUrl == "foo")
    {
        // do something relating to foo
    }
    else if(req.originalUrl == "bar")
    {
        // do something relating to bar
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
});

connect.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

So what is used to organize this? Do I need to make a get handler, put handler, delete handler, post handler, etc- and pass the "files" to a switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Jim has said, I would also add another patterns which can make your code cleaner.

### Verify route parameters in separate functions

If you use a route with a parameters, say, `app.get('/blog/:slug', ...` then you can use [`app.param`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) in order to verify if a given `slug` exist and perform necessary actions (send `404` or pass your request to another route if there is no that `slug` in your database or load a blog post identified by the given `slug`) e.g.

```
 function slugParam (req, res, next, slug) {
    Post.findBySlug({ slug: slug }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, 'SERVER ERROR');
        if (!post) return res.send(404);

        res.locals.post = post; // you will be able to access 'post' in your template
        next();
    })
}
```

And when you setup you application you have to call app.param e.g.

```
app.param('slug', slugParam);
```

With that approach you won't need to check in your request handler if a post identified by a give slug exist - very clean approach.

### Split request handler function into *middleware* functions

You can also split your request handler function into several smaller (cleaner) functions and call them sequentially (actually express will call them for you). Let's say, you build a discussion forum and you have a route like this:

```
app.get('/forum/:fid/thread/:tid', function(){
    // ...
})
```

You would need to handle forum and thread loading in a single function - very quickly you will see spaghetti code (especially that both operations will be executed asynchronously). In order to *fix* it you can split that functions into independent ones responsible for one a single functionality e.g. load forum, load thread, etc.

Example:

```
function loadFormum (req, res, next) {
    Forum.load(/* params here */, function (err, forum) {
        if (err) return res.send(500);
        if (!forum) return res.send(404);

        res.locals.forum = forum;
        next();
    })
}

function loadThread (req, res, next) {
    // you can use forum from res.locals.forum here 
    Forum.findThread(/* params here */, function (err, thread) {
        if (err) return res.send(500);
        if (!thread) return res.send(404);

        res.locals.thread = thread;
        next();
    })
}

app.get('/forum/:fid/thread/:tid', loadFormum, loadThread, function(){
    // cleaner code
})
```

Or

```
var forumMiddleware = [loadForum, loadThread]

app.get('/forum/:fid/thread/:tid', forumMiddleware, function(){
    // cleaner code
})
```

With that approach, functions may depend on each other i.e. `loadForum` loads a model, which is then used by `loadThread`. You may use as many middleware functions as you want to in order to keep your code clear.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 3):

express.js has a very robust routing engine built in.  You should look at the [application routing documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) and become familiar with it.

To answer your question, you *could* do:

```
app.get('/foo', function(req,res){
  // foo 
})

app.get('/bar', function(req,res){
  // bar 
})
```

Or, you could use a parameter value

```
app.get('/api/:action', function(req,res){
  // action can be foo, bar, whatever... 
  // access action from req.params['action']
})
```

Or, you can use regex like the docs show:

```
app.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){
  var from = req.params[0];
  var to = req.params[1] || 'HEAD';
  res.send('commit range ' + from + '..' + to);
});
```

But, yes, you should declare each verb separately.

Comment: Survey says: number one answer!

Comment: Any recommended frameworks to manage all of these verbs? I could do it myself but I all too often reinvent the wheel when I shouldn't.

Comment: Express.js supports the verbs you'll need.  `app.post` responds to all post request matching your criteria, `app.get` -> get, `app.delete` -> delete. `app.all` responds to all (used for auth and whatnot).